# How to get a parameter in the label of a plot?

Tags: r

I'm pretty sure you can help me:
I created some function which depends on some parameters (e.g. n). Then I plot a density and I want to label it with the n I entered as the parameter of the function.
To be more specific:

```
plot(function(x) dnorm(x,0,1), main="n=...")
lines(density(y), col = 'red')
```

I want the "..." to be automatically 100 when I used my function with n=100 (instead of always editing the function).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `paste0()`:

```
n <- 100
plot(function(x) dnorm(x,0,1), main=paste0("n=",n))
lines(density(y), col = 'red')
```

- `paste0()` is slightly more convenient here since `paste()` uses space-separation by default
- `main=sprintf(n=%d",n)` should work as well